# the numerator and denominator is not aligned well?

Tags: fractions

Here is the my code:

```
 $\sup_{v\neq 0}\frac{|Av|}{\|v\|^2}$
```

it displays as follow:

[image]

But it doesn't look very well. I want the subscript to be under the `sup` and the fraction to aligned well.

Comment: subscripts are in that position in inline math, if you used display math `\[..\]` they would move under. the fraction parts are centred, You did not say what alternative you would like, if you centre the denominator without taking account of the ^2 do you extend the rule on the left to compensate, or allow the 2 to hang out past the rule or...

Comment: `$\sup_{v\neq 0}\frac{|Av|}{\rule{.4em}{0pt}\|v\|^2}$`

Comment: As David says, putting this is display math will do what you want. If you really want this to be in-lined then use `$\sup\limits_{v\neq 0}\frac{|Av|}{\|v\|^2}$ `.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks, I see that subscripts are indeed in different position when in inline and display environment.